# Disk IO per process in cent os

Tags: linux, memory, io, cpu-usage, disk-io

I have three java processes running on cent os.

I want to monitor disk io for these processes individually and I want to find out minimum, maximum and average disk io for them in a given time frame.

I looked at **IOTOP** command for this thinking that I can run a script over IOTOP output to get min, max and average values.

But when I ran IOTOP command using process id, I found that it is not showing any IO in those process ids.

Then I ran following command: **iotop -o**, and I saw that IOTOP is reporting activity on thread level in java processes.

I would like to get the disk io on process level in linux and I assume that io for all the threads belonging to the process should be accounted on process level.

**What command I can use for such output ?**

**Is there any tool which can also find min, max and average of these values for given time window ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `iotop -p process_id`.

To get min, max and average values you need to use monitoring system

Comment: I have already tried that. My issue is say my java application spawns 2 threads and IO activity is going in those two threads. then I can't see that IO activity using process id of main java process. I can see that activity is going on using **iotop -o** command, where iotop displays **TID** in results which is thread id. What I want is the result of child threads combined at main process level.